# window is not defined in console of SUBLIME TEXT editor

Tags: javascript, sublimetext

I am trying to run a simple JavaScript program using sublime text's console, found [here](https://pawelgrzybek.com/javascript-console-in-sublime-text/).

```js
var clientData ={
 id: 123,
 fullName: 'Not set',
 setFullName: function (fName, lName) {
  this.fullName = fName + " "+ lName;

 }
}

function getInput(firstName, lastName, callback) {
 if (typeof(callback==="function")) {
  callback(firstName, lastName);
 }
}

getInput("Alex", "Smith", clientData.setFullName)

console.log(window.fullName);
```

Even though it works perfectly fine in the browser, I am not able to use the `window` object as it throws me the following error in the **sublime text's console**:

```
console.log(window.fullName);
        ^
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Desktop/My JS Exercises/callbackFnsOnObjs.js:18:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

I did a lot of research, but couldn't come up with the exact reason why it is throwing this error here. Any help and possible remedy will be very useful.

Comment: "no clue about the editor but" Does the linter/evv know it is running in the context of a browser? Not all envs that run JavaScript have window.

Comment: The short answer is that in a browser, it's JavaScript, the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and a few other APIs. With node, JavaScript acts like any other programming language: you can open files, use databases, etc. There's no `window` or `document` though, just the `console`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the tool you are using to run your javascript is `node`.  Node is a headless environment; it doesn't have a DOM, because it is just the V8 engine, it's not a web browser.

You can get around this by adding a declaration for window at the top of your code:

`global.window = {}`

Answer (score 0):

`window` is a global object for the browser.

`global` is a global object for NodeJS(Most of the editors that run JavaScript uses NodeJS)

https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global